# Is there a way to do Alamofire requests with retries

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a lot of places in the code where Alamofire request/response are handled.

Each of this requests may fail because of some intermittent problem (the most common is flaky network).

I would like to be able to retry requests 3 times before bailing out.

The straightforward method would be to having something like that

```
var errorCount = 0
func requestType1() {
   let request = Alamofire.request(...).responseJSON { response in
       if (isError(response) && errorCount < 3) {
          errorCount += 1
          request1()
       } 
       if (isError(response)) {
          handleError()
       }

       handleSuccess()
   }
}
```

However, I dislike this approach A LOT for multiple reasons. The most obvious is that I will need to implement such code for each request type (and I have something like 15 of them).

I am curios whether there is way to do something like (where the changes are minimal and non intrusive)

```
let request = Alamofire.request(..., **3**)
```

Comment: Could you make a wrapper that takes the request as an ending block? So then instead of calling the request directly, you have the same request code in the block but call the wrapper? Makes it easier to change the code.

Comment: Carlos. I think you are right. I overlooked this :). Do you want to write up as an answer?

Comment: Sure, give me a bit of time and I'll do that

Comment: @VictorRonin any you explain how you got it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the bits of syntactic sugar you get with Swift is you can use this:

```
public func updateEvents(someNormalParam: Bool = true, someBlock: (Void->Void))
```

Like this:

```
updateEvents(someNormalParam: false) {...}
```

Note the block is outside the () of the updateEvents function, contrary to where you'd normally expect it. It works only if the block is the last thing in the declaration of the function.

That means if you happen to have a block such as your Alamofire request, you can effectively wrap it with your retry functionality. One slightly complicating issue is you want to call a block within the block. Not a big deal:

```
func retryWrapper(alamoBlock: (Void->Request)) {
   alamoblock().responseJSON() {
       //Your retry logic here
   }
}
```

And you use it like so:

```
retryWrapper() {
    Alamofire.request(method, targetUrl, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding)
}
```

Meaning all you have to do is find your Alamofire calls and wrap them in { } and put retryWrapper() before. The retry logic itself is only there once.

Comment: I am little confused here .. what us responseJSON() here?

Comment: I'm a little rusty but it looks like the block returns a Request, which has a function that turns it into JSON

Comment: Cant we use requestRetrier?

Comment: No idea. Things might have moved on since I wrote this.

Answer (score 24):

Alamofire 4.0 has a `RequestRetrier` protocol you can use.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#request-retrier

Example:

```
class OAuth2Handler: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {
    public func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: RequestRetryCompletion) {
        if let response = request.task.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {
            completion(true, 1.0) // retry after 1 second
        } else {
            completion(false, 0.0) // don't retry
        }

        // Or do something with the retryCount
        // i.e. completion(request.retryCount <= 10, 1.0)
    }
}

let sessionManager = SessionManager()
sessionManager.retrier = OAuth2Handler()

sessionManager.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: I am using the Alamofire.request.... approach and how I can fit in the requestretrier?

Comment: right now I use the APIRouter and URLRequestConvertible approach,         AF.request(request).validate().responseJSON { (response)...... I am setting up the headers in the APIRouter.... with the Retrier.. looks like I need to change my whole approach? Or is there any easy way to use Retrier with minimum impact.. I use this approach https://medium.com/@AladinWay/write-a-networking-layer-in-swift-4-using-alamofire-and-codable-part-1-api-router-349699a47569

Comment: @anoop4real Please open a new question for others to advise you so the comments stay relevant on this answer

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem, and I got the requests to be retried using the `RequestRetrier`, `should` method and `request.retryCount`. Something like it:

```
// MARK: - RequestRetry

public func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {
    lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }


    if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse{
        if response.statusCode == 401 {
            requestsToRetry.append(completion)

            getToken { (expires, _) in
               _ = SessionCountdownToken.sharedInstance.startCount(expirationTime: expires)
            }
        } else {

            if request.retryCount == 3 { completion(false, 0.0 ); return}
            completion(true, 1.0)
            return
        }
    } else {
        completion(false, 0.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is lock in the first line?

Comment: @jayantrawat I guess its a `NSRecursiveLock()` instance

Answer (score 1):

I've created one wrapper class for request retrier should function.
https://gist.github.com/daljeetseera/7ce2b53b8a88d8a5e9b172c0495c6455

And used the request retrier in session manager required for request.

```
static let sharedManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        let requestRet = NetworkRequestRetrier()
        manager.retrier = requestRet
        return manager
    }()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alamofire 5 and Above**

Alamofire provides an inbuilt class `RetryPolicy` which confirms to `RequestRetrier` protocol. `RetryPolicy` provides a default implementation to retry requests which failed due to system errors, such as network connectivity.  [source](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/RetryPolicy.swift)

Set the `RetryPolicy` while creating the `Alamofire.Session` object in the `NetworkClient`

```
class NetworkClient {
    
    private let session: Alamofire.Session = {
        let session = Session(interceptor: RetryPolicy())
        return session
    }()

    ....

}
```