# Alamofire best way to recall api on failure

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

I need to recall the api when receiving an specific error say error code -1005.

I want to handle this in Alamofire files so that it can work with all api in project.

I was handling this in ObjC's AFNetworking in **dataTaskWithHTTPMethod** with below code:-

```
if (failure)
        {
            if (error.code == -1005)
            {
                [self POST:URLString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:success failure:failure];
            }           
}
```

Can anyone help me to do this in Alamofire?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I couldn't define from where Alamofire calls success or failure block for given request

Comment: Did you read this https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: yes u can do it

Comment: Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422589/is-there-a-way-to-do-alamofire-requests-with-retries)

Answer (score 1):

lets understand with One Example.

let me guess as you have created one class for managing all the webservice realted stuff there. (**if not yet then it will be good to create one for best practice**).

Okay now create two **typealias** for managing response.

here it is :-

here i assume again that you want whole **dictionary** for success response and **error** for failure response.

```
typealias successCompletion = (([String:Any]) -> ())
typealias failureCompletion = ((Error) -> ())
```

now here its one **WSManager Class** for ***handling all the API Related stuff there.***

```
    class AlamofireManager {

   static func sampleFunctionOfWebService(successCompletion:successCompletion , failureCompletion:failureCompletion) {

        if success {
            successCompletion(["Key":"success"])
        } else {
            failureCompletion(-1005 as! Error)
        }
    }
}
```

> you need to pass the both typealias in function for getting CallBack
>   in desired class.
>
> Here for only understanding purpose we are going to pass static
>   dictionary :-> ["Key":"success"] and static -1005 as Error.

**now how to use this function in our desired class?**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func wsCalling() {

        AlamofireManager.sampleFunctionOfWebService(successCompletion: { (dict) in

            print(dict)

        }) { (error) in

            if error.code == -1005 {
                self.wsCalling() // recall API Again
            } else {
                // your other logic
            }

        }
    }

}
```

> I have not mentioned here for URLSeeionTask and All , its good thing
>   to manage URLSeeionTask. If you have a instance of URLSeeionTask of
>   Previous API then cancel it first and then try to recall it again.

**Happy Coding.**

Answer (score 0):

```
 //MARK: Your method

   func hitYourService(){
            showActivityIndicator(decision: true, inViewConroller: self, animated: true)
            let deviceToken = HelpingClass.userDefaultForKey(key: "deviceToken")
            let paramDict = ["email":txtFEmail.text ?? "" ,"password":txtFPassword.text ?? "" ,"device_token":deviceToken]

            NetworkManager.instance().hitPostServiceJsonForm(paramDict, myReqURL: ServiceMethods.serviceBaseURL+ServiceMethods.login, unReachable: {
                // Here you can handle the case if there is no internet connection
            }) { (response) in
                showActivityIndicator(decision: false, inViewConroller: self, animated: true)
                if response != nil{
                    if  response?["error_code"] as! Int == 0{
                        //Handle your response

                    }else{
                        //Show error
                        showHudWithMessage(message: response?["error_msg"] as! String, inViewConroller: self, animated: true, hideAfter: 2)
                    }
                }else{
                    //You can hit back your service
                   self.hitYourService()
                }

            }
        }


//MARK: Alamofire method to hit service, written in NetworkManager class        


        func hitPostServiceJsonForm(_ params:Dictionary<String,Any>, myReqURL:String, unReachable:(() -> Void),handler:@escaping ((Dictionary<String,Any>?) -> Void)) {
            if networkReachable() == false {
                unReachable()
            }
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: myReqURL)!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            print_debug(object: "ReqParameter: \(String(describing: params))") // http url response

            //JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)

            request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])



            Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
                // SwiftLoader.hide()
                print_debug(object: "Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
                print_debug(object: "Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
                print_debug(object: "Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

                print_debug(object: "Result.value \(String(describing: response.result.value))")
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                        print_debug(object: "Json Response: \(jsonDict)") // serialized json response
                        handler(jsonDict)
                    }
                    else{
                        handler(nil)
                    }
                    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print("Server Response: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
                    }
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    handler(nil)
                    print_debug(object: error)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I want to do this in alamofire's class so that It will work with all api calling

Comment: you can place this method -> hitPostServiceJsonForm in your network class

Comment: see in my project I have called api at many placed, with your solution I need to change all the api calling in my network class. What I want is to add code of error handling in Alamore class so that it will reflect everywhere

Comment: You can simply return nil in case service fails and check back it in your method..If nil is found hit back the serivce

Comment: I know what you are saying, but my problem is I need to write this handling everywhere I call the API. I want a centralize way where I can handle and call api again.