# How to request api call repeatedly until get result in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, swift3, alamofire

I need to know how can I call api repeatedly until get specific status, like 10.

in my case, when I got another result, just call error message in toast.
but my team wants to call it repeatedly for purchase process in Appstore.

below is my code example.

```
func deliveryProduct(json:JSON, receiptData:String) {


    if let _userInfo = Authentication.userInfo {
        if let account = _userInfo.account {

            let dict:[String: Any] = ["myData":data]

            getVerifyBillingiOS(dict: dict, completion: {
                value in

            let json = JSON(value)

                let myStatus = json["status"].intValue

                if myStatus == 10 {
                   print("Result Success")
                }else{
                    print("Result Failed")
                }

            })
        }
    }
}


 func postReceiptData(dict: [String: Any], completion: ((Any)->())?) {
    let url = "myServerUrl"
    Alamofire.requestURL(string: url, method: .post, parameter: dict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: applicationHeader(), completion: {
        success, response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)

            let status = json["status"].intValue
            print(json["status"])
            print("~~~~~~")

            // Success status = 10, failure status = -10

            if let _completion = completion {
                _completion(value)
                }

        case .failure(let error):

            if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                Util.showDefaultToast(message: "Network Error")
            }

            if let _completion = completion {
                _completion(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422589/is-there-a-way-to-do-alamofire-requests-with-retries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
print("Result Failed")
```

just recall the function , i can't make it by code because the two functions you mentioned are not related to each other so i can't figure what to do, however recall the function that calls the api instead of printing error (or do both) this will make it keep trying till it works

Update : 
after `let json = JSON(value)`

you should call

```
self.deliveryProduct(json: json, receiptData: receiptData)
```

and below `print("Result Failed")`
you should call `postReceiptData` again

i hope it's clear now

Comment: Alsh, I sorry to bothering you..I tried to put deliveryProduct method instead of print, but it's not called again..! I input as below in else section; 
self.deliveryProduct(json: json, receiptData: receiptData)

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach. Get the status code using call back, check if it is required one, else call the function making request again. Keep this process going until you get the desired code.

Sample code:

```
func getData()
{
    requestForDataWithURL(url: "http://localhost:8000/getData") { (code) in
        if code == 200
        {
            print("success")
        }
        else
        {
            self.getData()
        }
    }
}

func requestForDataWithURL(url:String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ statusCode: Int)->Void)
{
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if data != nil
        {
            do{
                let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                let someStruct = SomeStruct.init(dict: responseDict as! [String : Int])
                print(someStruct)
                completionHandler(someStruct.status!)
            }catch
            {

            }

        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Struct used in above code

```
struct SomeStruct {
var status:Int?
init(dict: [String:Int])
{
    status = dict["status"]
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution suggested by @Fahadsk is also good and working fine. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422589/is-there-a-way-to-do-alamofire-requests-with-retries)

You can also do as below.

```
func postReceiptData(dict: [String: Any], completion: ((Any)->())?) {
    let url = "myServerUrl"
    Alamofire.requestURL(string: url, method: .post, parameter: dict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: applicationHeader(), completion: {
        success, response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)

            let status = json["status"].intValue
            print(json["status"])
            print("~~~~~~")

            // Success status = 10, failure status = -10

           let myStatus = (json["status"]

           if myStatus == 10 {
               print("Result Success")
            }else{
            // Call your method again
                postReceiptData(your argument)
            }

            if let _completion = completion {
                _completion(value)
                }

        case .failure(let error):

            if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                Util.showDefaultToast(message: "Network Error")
            }

            if let _completion = completion {
                _completion(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
print("Result Failed")
```

Put this

```
self.deliveryProduct(json: json, receiptData: receiptData)
```